# Get facebook page from a Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook

i was always curious to which pages some like buttons are for, and if inspected it only contain a link to an application id, which when accessed gives "not found" error.

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FGoGoEntertainment&send=false&layout=standard&width=230&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=25&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

so is there a good way to extract the page from the button?

Comment: In this case the page is: www.facebook.com/GoGoEntertainment. It is just url_encoded. So the href parameter is what you want.

Comment: >_< thought it was page type, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The href parameter is what you want. Here is how to exclude it easily:

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FGoGoEntertainment&send=false&layout=standard&width=230&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=25&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$url = parse_url($url);
parse_str($url['query'], $query);
var_dump($query['href']);
```